# RegEx which tests if sentence contain every letter from polish alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function isPangram(sentence) {
  const polishSpecial = /[śćóźąęłżń]/;
  const RegEx = /(\w).*\1/;
  return !RegEx.test(sentence);
}
```

Mine regular expression only checks whether the letter is repeating itself. I want also add these polish special characters to the main RegEx.

The point is that sentence can only have one letter from [a-z] and [śćóźąęłżń], then it's true. If sentence doesn't have even one letter from [a-z] or [śćóźąęłżń], then it's false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const ContainsAllPolishLetters = (str) => 
 { 
   return [...new Set(str.match(/[A-Za-zżźćńółęąśŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ]/g))].length == 64;
}
console.log(ContainsAllPolishLetters("...AaĄąBbCcĆćDdEeĘęFfGgHhIiJjKkLlŁłMmNnŃńOoÓóPpRrSsŚśTtUuWwYyZzŹźŻż..."));
console.log(ContainsAllPolishLetters("...A tu mamy za mało polskich liter..."));
```

**Details**:

- `.match(/[A-Za-zżźćńółęąśŻŹĆĄŚĘŁÓŃ]/g` - extracts all Polish letters from a `str` string
- `[...new Set(<result_of_Step_1>)]` - removes duplicate letters from the array
- `<result_of_the_above>.length == 64` - checks if the count of unique letters is equal to 64, 32 lower- and 32 uppercase Polish letter count. If yes, the return value is `true`, otherwise, `false`.